# Create Node.js Website on remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.js and I've been going through some tutorials. I've been able to make a simple web page in Node.js and run it as its own server from the command line on my desk top. However, I would like to create it to use it as a website that others can access, as well. Therefore I was wondering how can I host a web site built with Node.js on a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

If you have public IP then you can host the website on your server

Option 2:

Find a service provider who can host your Node.js application. e.g heroku

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check out [Heroku](http://heroku.com).  They offer a very simple hosting service at a variety of pricing tiers (including free) with a wide variety of add-ons.  Deployment is as simple as pushing to a remote GitHub repository.